# uninstallation didn't work

Tags: 14.04, software-center, uninstall

I recently installed "Battle for Wesnoth" and  the "BfW map editor" from software center. 
I uninstalled it with Software Center and now the game is shown as uninstalled there.

However, I can still start and play the game, "re-uninstalling" doesn't seem to be possible.
Can anyone please help me uninstalling the game and the map editor? They need quite a lot of space on my harddrive and I'm getting annoying update notifications all the time.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wesnoth-*
```

If you want exactly to see packages containing `wesnoth` that you've installed then run:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i wesnoth
```

Then you can purge those packages by one manually with `apt-get remove --purge` command.

You can also manually search for `config`(cache) folder of the game in your Home Directory just open your Home Directory and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and type in search bar `wesnoth` and delete what's related to game.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem on Ubuntu 22.04: uninstalling from Sofware Center or by `apt remove` doesn't work. I figured out it was a flatpak app and have deleted it from terminal.

Try to check if its a flatpak app, `flatpak list`, and then uninstall it (`flatpack uninstall wesnoth`). But cache and some assets could be remained (I don't know how to check it and clear so no help here).